# Vue Vuex: old data remains for some time before computed property changes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm new to `vuex` and I still I have over used it. For say, I have a `product` lists in my `store` state. When I view one `product` i make `axios` call with that `product.id` and commit the product data into `currentProduct` state. Then if I view another product then the page is rendered with `currentProduct` state i.e old 
 data at first then after my `action` `commits`.. it is then updated to newly fetched `currentProduct` then vue changes my view data to new data. The `user` can clearly see old data being replaced by new data. 
But I want to load the page only after new data is commited to my `state`.

```
`store.js`

state :{
    productList:{},
    currentProduct:{
     id:'',name:'',price:'','seller'
    }
},
mutations:{
    UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT : (state, data) =>{
     state.currentProduct = Object.assign({},state.currentProduct, data);
    }

},
actions:{
    fetchProducts(){
     const response = fetch...... // logic to fetch product
     commit('UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT', response.data);
    }
}
```

**My render page:**

This page displays the lists of my products

```
'productList.vue'

<div v-for="product in productList" @click="viewProduct(product.id)">
    <p>{{product.name}}</p>
</div>

computed(){

    ...mapState(['productList'])

},
methods:{
    viewProduct(product_id){
        this.$store.state.dispatch('fetchProducts', product_id);
    }
}
```

This page renders the view of that particular product

```
`product.vue`

<div>
    <p>{{currentProduct.name}}</p>
</div>

computed(){

    ...mapState(['currentProduct'])

}
```

In my `product.vue` first old data is shown then after some time new data replaces it ... Something is missing.. I want to see the new data directly with out seeing old data being replaced by new data. Is there a way around `vuex`

Comment: If you are using Vue Router, you can use the `beforeRouteEnter` / `beforeRouteUpdate` hooks to update the data firts before opening the component.

Answer (score 0):

The key part is:

> I want to load the page only after new data is commited to my state

You want to make the async methods follow each other. There is a cool way to do that.

I guess in the `fetchProducts()` an axios get / post the data. Because axios is based on promise, you can return with it.

```
fetchProducts() {
 return axios.get('/get/some/data')
    .then(r => { // commit and stuff
     })
    .catch(e => { // error handling
     })
}
```

Then you can easily do this:

```
this.$store.state.dispatch('fetchProducts', product_id)
 .then(r=> {if(r){ // get the data from vuex 
 } else { // error
 })
 .catch(e => {});
```

The then of dispatch runs after the then of axis. (e.g.: If there are two axios call what have to run sequentially, you can call the second one in the then method of first, and it solves the problem.)

I hope you understand this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple **solution** would be to reset the data to a initial value when the actions are loaded/dispatched.

So, try editing your code from this:

```
actions:{
    fetchProducts(){
     const response = fetch...... // logic to fetch product
     commit('UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT', response.data);
    }
}
```

To this:

```
actions:{
    fetchProducts(){
     // Add below line to reset the state when loading.
     commit('UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT', null);
     /***********************************************/
     const response = fetch...... // logic to fetch product
     commit('UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT', response.data);
    }
}
```

The above solution worked for me. Hope this works for you or someone else too.

Answer (score -2):

For this you should use async await so that your component will only be updated after your new data is retrieved.

```
async fetchProducts(){
    await const response = fetch...... // logic to fetch product
    commit('UPDATE_CURRENT_PRODUCT', response.data);
   }
```

And the same in your viewProduct method.
Refer following llink for more details(last example on the page)
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Comment: that is not the case here.. I have already some data on my 'currentProduct' i.e previously fetched data so even its async await it will still fetches the old `currentProduct` data and updated it later after `await` is `resolved`

Comment: You can set state.productList = {} in mutation and call that on click of your div tag.

Comment: Yes you can try that